# ¿Cómo arreglar el problema de orientación de libros generados en EPUB versión 3 y subidos a Google Play?

Tags: google-play

Anteriormente generaba el contenido de mis libros en EPUB 2 y cuando los subía a Google Play Libros no había ningún problema, los libros cambiaban de posición al girar la pantalla del dispositivo.

Cuando mi software de generación de EPUB cambió a la versión 3, ya los libros que subo a Google Play no giran, sólo se muestran en vertical.

¿Cómo puedo resolverlo?

[Plantee el problema en el foro de ayuda de Google](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-es/kHMQ34ebT8M;context-place=mydiscussions), pero me dijeron que no había solución para eso, que estaba habilitado sólo en algunos libros.

[Pregunté también en el foro en inglés](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/books-on-google-play-partner/sVeppnIkLKQ;context-place=mydiscussions) y nadie me respondió.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es realmente frustante cuando tienes un libro que funcionaba bien al girar la pantalla y de repente esa funcionalidad desaparece (a mi me pasó, como digo en la pregunta al cambiar de EPUB 2 a EPUB 3) y no sé por qué motivo.

Finalmente, leyendo la [documentación de EPUB](http://www.idpf.org/epub/fxl/#property-orientation) encontré la solución, se trataba de algo muy sencillo, poner en el EPUB la sigueinte etiqueta `meta`:

```
<meta property="rendition:orientation">auto</meta>
```

Para hacerlo, hay que abrir el contenido del EPUB con algún editor de EPUBS donde se pueda ver el contenido, o sea el código interno del EPUB.

En mi caso he usado `Calibre`, que es un editor gratis. He abierto el EPUB para editar, he buscado el apartado `Miscelánea`y abierto el archivo `iBooks.opf` en edición (puede que, según el generador de EPUB el archivo se llame de otra forma, en ese caso habría que buscar donde se encuentra el archivo con extensión `.opf`). Dentro de ese archivo se encuentran los metadatos del EPUB, hay que agregar con mucho cuidado la etiqueta meta mencionada más arriba:

```
<meta property="rendition:orientation">auto</meta>
```

Siempre dentro del bloque:

```
  <metadata>

     ... aquí en cualquier parte, preferiblemente al final

  </metadata>
```

Luego hay que guardar los cambios y subir de nuevo el EPUB a PlayBooks Store. Y listo, nuestro libro se podrá leer en vertical o en horizontal.

> **Nota:** Antes de hacer esta manipulación conviene guardar una copia del EPUB original, por si algo sale mal.

Dejo una imagen de cómo se ve la operación usando `Calibre`. Escribo esta respuesta porque tardé años sin resolver este molesto problema por si puede servir a alguien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]